# Yii2 widget fileinput utf-8 charset problem

Tags: file-upload

I would like to upload a filename with utf-8 characters such as greek, german etc. The upload occurs successfully for both file size and type, unfortunately its filename is being replaced by strange characters. However when english characters for filename are used, there is no problem at all.

Any idea what it might be wrong with utf-8 characters regarding filename for this specific [Yii2 widget plugin](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput)?

I provide you with the filename being generated for utf-8 characters

[image]

and additionally the function source code that produces filename via _slugDefault (added extra line for no special characters).

[image]

Regards

Comment: Can you provide examples ( Copy and paste ) of the names being generated?

Comment: I just found the solution to my problem and thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it actually depends on the server OS file system language settings and not by the widget itself. So i used the following php function in my controller:

```
$file_name=iconv('UTF-8', 'language//TRANSLIT',$model->field);

$file->saveAs('files/'.$file_name);
```

Thanks a lot and i am indeed very happy to solve it on myself!